# Magento: Invoice and capture an authorized order

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am developing a module for a payment gateway that can authorize and capture in two different steps. So far I am able to authorize the order by running the following code:

```
class My_Gateway_Model_Method_Cc extends Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Cc
{
    protected $_code          = 'mycode';
    protected $_canSaveCc     = true;

    protected $_canRefund                   = true;
    protected $_isGateway                   = true;
    protected $_canAuthorize                = true;
    protected $_canCapture                  = true;
    protected $_canCapturePartial           = false;


    public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount){
        /* code to call the payment gateway and authorize the charge */
    }


    public function capture(Varien_Object $payment, $amount){
        /* some code to capture the payment */
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I place an order, and then I go into the invoicing panel I get this message:

> 'Invoice will be created without communication with payment gateway'

There is no option to capture the authorized payment nor it call the capture method when invoicing.

Comment: I have gone through the code, apparently Magento sets the transaction as closed or close == 1 on authorization. Therefore, it disables the option to capture payment on the backend. Any ideas how to prevent that from happening without hardcoding it?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found the solution:

Basically, Magento closes any authorization transaction by default, and it enables the option to capture the payment on invoice when the authorization transaction is open. So all you have to do is to configure the transaction to stay openend (not closed)

So here is what I did:

```
public function authorize(Varien_Object $payment, $amount)
{
    // Leave the transaction opened so it can later be captured in backend
    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(false);

    /*
     * Place all the code to connect with your gateway here!!!
     *
     */

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have set

```
$_isGateway = true;
```

So the you also need to set the gateway url

In your payment model, the one that extends `Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract`, you'll need to implement the method:

```
function getOrderPlaceRedirectUrl() {
    return 'http://www.where.should.we.pay.com/pay';
}
```

Typically you redirect the user to a page on your site, /mymodule/payment/redirect for example, and then handle the redirection logic in the action of the controller. This keeps your payment model clean and stateless, while allowing you to some some kind of "You are now being transferred to the gateway for payment" message.

Save everything you need to decide where to redirect to in a session variable, again typically `Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')`.

Magento have a pretty solid, if messy, implementation of this for Paypal standard. You can checkout how they do it in `app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/{Model/Standard.php,controllers/StandardController.php}`.

Comment: Thanks. I will change $_isGateway to false as it is actually not one. It processes the payment in the backend. The problem is that it closes the payment transaction by default. I will autoanswer my question as I have found the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this [blog](http://excellencemagentoblog.com/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based) **Magento Transactions** section at the end.

```
if($result['status'] == 1){  // on success result from payment gateway
    $payment->setTransactionId($result['transaction_id']);
    $payment->setIsTransactionClosed(1);
    $payment->setTransactionAdditionalInfo(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment_Transaction::RAW_DETAILS, array('key1'=>'value1','key2'=>'value2'));
}
```